# How to return error Message in Output from Trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create trigger that ensures that the same `shop_id` should not repeat more than 3 times, and if user tries to add more than 3 records for the same `shop_id`, it will throw an error message.
I have written the following trigger but its giving me error message.

```
  IF
    (sum(distinct(shop_id)) >3 )
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT := 'You cannot insert more than 3 Records';
    END IF;
```

Its giving me following error message.

```
    MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'SET MESSAGE_TEXT 
:= 'check constraint on
```

Kindly check this and guide me what i am doing wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot insert more than 3 Records';
```

[SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

Comment: And how should I use of that message in php?